# Open a pdf in React by getting path from Node JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, pdf

How can I open pdfs in Reactjs which are saved in local drive and it's path is coming from backend(ExpressJS)?

Actually, I am showing some data in Table and each row of Table is a link in itself. I want to open a related pdf by clicking on a row. Since, DB is Mongo, so I can provide a seperate link to each document for pdf. As of now, I am getting data from back-end using axios. How can I write the code such that I can open pdf by clicking the rows of a Table using links from back-end?

Please help me how can I do so.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code :**
Just pass this code in view handler

```
viewHandler = async () => {
    axios(your Api url, {
      method: "GET",
      responseType: "blob"
      //Force to receive data in a Blob Format
    })
      .then(response => {
        //Create a Blob from the PDF Stream
        const file = new Blob([response.data], {
          type: "application/pdf"
        });
        //Build a URL from the file
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        //Open the URL on new Window
        window.open(fileURL);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Comment: I tried this code but pdf is not opening. My data is coming from back-end like this:

{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5d8ce1f234e1c2c2eb5c226"
  },
  "papertype": "Maths",
  "paperLocation": "Maths_Paper/Maths.pdf"
}

fileURL is producing some output but I am not getting it.
How can I tweak this code to open the pdf file?

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the PDF data from API endpoint

axios (`${apiURL}/PDF`, {

method:'GET',

Answer (score 0):

Code at Back-end (NodeJs):

//id is unique for each Link (row) in a table, based on 'id', data is fetched from DB and pdf is returned from Node for that particular id

```
app.get('/papers/:id', (req, res) => {
  connectionForPdf(req.params.id).then((data)=>{
  var tempFile=data.paperLocation; //data.paperLocation physical path of the paper 
                                   //fetched from DB
        fs.readFile(tempFile, function (err,data){
            res.contentType("application/pdf");
            res.send(data);
        });  
      })
      .catch(error=>{
        console.log('Shit');
      })
})

connectionForPdf=(id)=>{
  return mongoose.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then((database)=> {
    return exampleModel.findOne({_id:id}).then(data=>{
      if(data) {
        return data.toObject();
      }                                                                                     
      database.close();
    }).catch(error=>{
      console.log('Con')
    })

  .catch((error)=>{
    console.log('not connected')
    let err=new Error("Couldn't connect");
    err.status=500;
    throw err;
  })
}
```

Code at front-end (ReactJs):

// id is passed on onClick() of each Link (Row)

```
handleClick=(id)=>{
       const viewHandler = async () => {
        axios('http://localhost:3001/papers/'+id, {
          method: "GET",
          responseType: "blob"
          //Force to receive data in a Blob Format
        })
          .then(response => {
            //Build a URL from the file
            var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            //Open the URL on new Window
            window.open(fileURL);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });

        }
         viewHandler();
      }
```